Asymptotics on coefficients of bivariate generating function
In my work, I've come across the following generating function:
$$F(x,y)=\frac{1}{x-y-x^2-y^2+x^2y}.$$
I'd like to estimate (upper/lower bound, at the very least) the $x^ay^b$ coefficient of $F$.
I've tried the standard tricks for univariate generating functions (e.g. binomial theorem, expanding $\frac{1}{1-t}$, etc.) to no avail. What's the general approach for this type of problem?

As I understand it, this general task even for rational bivariate generating functions is surprisingly hard, but you should be able to do it using the material in Pemantle and Wilson's Analytic Combinatorics in Several Variables: https://www2.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/ACSV.pdf

This rational function does not have a power series expansion since the denominator has constant term 0.
